# VBA Form Is (automatically) Tied/Bound To ActiveWorksheet When calling Form.Show vbmodeless

Tags: excel, vba

It's been difficult to describe to google, but the scenario is as follows..

I have a button on the ribbon which is linked to a sub which will launch my form:

```
Sub Start()
    MyForm.Init
    MyForm.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

The code called by my form does some things and create a new workbook. When the new workbook is created the form disappears. When bring the form back, it pulls the workbook that was active when the form was shown. I want to have the new workbook active and the form active in order to perform more actions from the form with the new worksheet.

Is there another way to call/load the form in order to have it not "linked" to a workbook?

Comment: @braX This doesn't work because it activates the worksheet along with it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can be achieved but with using APIs `SetWindowPos` and `FindWindowA`. You can read about these APIs [Here](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/apilist.php)

Is this what you are trying?

**Code**:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const SWP_NOMOVE = 2
Private Const SWP_NOSIZE = 1    
Private Const FLAGS = SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE
Private Const HWND_TOPMOST = -1
Private Const HWND_NOTOPMOST = -2

Private Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, _
ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, _
ByVal cx As Long, ByVal cy As Long, _
ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function FindWindowA _
Lib "user32" (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Sub Sample()
    Dim hwnd As Long

    UserForm1.Show vbModeless

    '~~> Find the handle of the userform
    hwnd = FindWindowA("ThunderDFrame", UserForm1.Caption)

    '~~> Set the form as the top most window
    SetTopMostWindow hwnd, True
End Sub

Private Function SetTopMostWindow(hwnd As Long, Topmost As Boolean) As Long
    If Topmost = True Then
        SetTopMostWindow = SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, FLAGS)
    Else
        SetTopMostWindow = SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, FLAGS)
        SetTopMostWindow = False
    End If
End Function
```

**Testing**

1. Paste the code in the module of the workbook which has the userform.
2. Open two workbooks.
3. Replace `Userform1` with your userform name.
4. Run the proc `Sample`.

[image]

Comment: This is close...Form always stays on top... Try this. Create a new workbook in code from the form, then the form will be on top of the new workbook. Click into the form and it will automatically activate the first workbook.

Comment: Yes that is something you cannot get rid of (AFAIK) since the form is bound to the first workbook.